# Prove that $\tan 2A = \frac{2\tan A}{1- \tan^2 A} $

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that

$\tan 2A = \frac{2 \tan A}{1- \tan^2 A} $

using identities of $\sin 2A$ and $\cos 2A$

Can I get a hint on how do I start this ? 
Identities from $\sin 2A$ and $\cos 2A$ doesn't give me a $\tan A$ so how do I prove it ?

Comment: Have you written out the definition of $\tan(2A)$?

Comment: Start with $\tan 2A = \sin 2A/\cos 2A$ and just manipulate the fraction you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Use the *duplication formulæ* for sine and cosine:

$$\frac{\sin 2A}{\cos 2A}=\frac{2\sin A\cos A}{\cos^2A-\sin^2A}.$$

Comment: It might be better to use $\cos2A=\cos^2A-\sin^2A$ instead of $1-2\sin^2A$.

Comment: @BarryCipra: You' re right, it will require less transformations. Thanks!

Comment: @Bernard how do I form $\tan$ from that

Comment: Factor out $\cos^2A$ in the denominator and simplify.

Answer (score 3):

HINT

write down $\tan x$ as $\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$ and use identities